# setting pcregrep color default

Tags: grep, defaults

i know you can set grep color defaults using the environment variables `$GREP_OPTIONS` and `$GREP_COLOR`, but i can't seem to find any way to set the default color options with `pcregrep`...

i have `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` and `export GREP_COLOR='31'` in my /etc/profile right now, and want to have equivalent defaults for `pcregrep`.

tldr: how do i make `pcregrep` color matches by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i never did figure out how to do exactly what i wanted, but i got the same end result using an alias:

`alias pcregrep='pcregrep --color=auto'`